# Как задать условие в C# для StreamReader

Tags: c#, парсер, текст

Делаю парсинг текстового файла. Нужно задать условие: "если строка начинается с числа" и тд. Как это реализовать

Comment: Что-нибудь уже попробовали? Покажите.

Comment: Гугл не дал результатов. Сейчас более детально опишу что мне нужно.
Есть такие строки:
1.1 Текст
Описание первого пункта
1.2 Текст
и т.д.
Нужно выделить только 1.1 Текст(строка начинается с числа), а описание пропустить. Есть идеи, ибо, повторюсь, гугл не дал результатов?

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под «условием для `StreamReader`»? Внесите подробное описание в вопрос.

Comment: по идее нужно взять что то из строки , либо символы  -  в количестве скольки то знаков с начала строки или с такого то по счету символа по такой то по счету в строке , либо часть строки до разделителя ( split ) . разделителей может быть несколько в строке , соответственно можно брать split ("" ;0) , split ("";1) , split ("";2) и тд ....
смотря как фаил сохранен и что в нём...

Comment: @Eikhner спасибо, но вопрос уже решил :)

Comment: @Vlad ну так хоть напишите, как решили.

Comment: @VladD используя регулярные выражения

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая штука, как `String.StartWith(s1, s2)`;
Где `s1` строка, которую ты проверяешь, а `s2` - подстрока, наличие которой проверяеться в начале

Имеем следующий код:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@puth);  
string buffer; // буфер для считывания строк  

while(!sr.EndOfStream)  
{  
    buffer = sr.ReadLine();
    if (String.StartWith(buffer, i.ToString()) // где і - нужное число, преобразованое в строку
    {
        // выполняешь нужные действия
    }
}
sr.Close();
```

Так же можно создать метод, который будет выполнять нужные действие в зависимости от содержащего числа в начале считаной строки, например:

```
public static string DoSomeOperationWithString(string s, string subS)
{
    string result;
    if(subS == "1.1")
    {
        // выполняешь действия, записывая результат в переменную result, потом возвращаешь ее
    }
    else if(subS == "1.2")
    {
        // выполняешь действия, записывая результат в переменную result, потом возвращаешь ее
    }
    return result;
}
```

Метод вызываешь  в теле цикла считывания, вместо `if`, и проверка осуществляеться непосредственно в методе. Так же можно создать подметоды, котоыре будут вызываться из этого метода.
Надеюсь, я овтетил на твой вопрос.

А вообще, ответ на твой вопрос есть вот тут:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx

PS: мой первый ответ на StackOverFlow:)

Comment: А почему у вас `sr` не в `using`? Если внутри случится исключение, то файл останется открытым.

Comment: А так вообще с почином :)

Comment: Метод `StartsWith` не статический. Приведённый код не скомилируется. Хорошо бы поправить.

Comment: Вместо String.StartWith(text, param) пиши someText.StartWith(param), где someText - проверяемая строка, а param - проверочная подстрока
И да, по поводу using немного упустил

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден! Реализовал при помощи Regex(регулярные выражения):

```
string line = sr.ReadLine();
RegexOptions ignoreCase = RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^\s+[0-9]", ignoreCase);
Match m = reg.Match(line);
```